# How to use Regex to return True on a user's input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

I was looking around and found the re.match to validate a user's input on a phone number. I have the print function there to debug, and it keeps coming back as None type instead of True. Is there a formatting error that I am overlooking?

```
def validation():
    flag = True
    while flag:
        phone = input('Enter your phone number (XXX-XXX-XXXX): ')
        answer = re.match(r'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]}{4}$',phone)
        print(answer)
```

Basically, I am trying to get the function to validate that the number is in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX and when it is then I can continue, but right now all I am focusing on is returning True on the re.match. The rest of the code I will do after.

Comment: Ummmm.... just `return bool(answer)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have mistyped '}' in your regex.

Your solution looks correct. This will be the regex to match the phone number format.

```
re.match(r'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$',phone)
```

And you can write the below code for validation of the phone number and return the boolean value from the function.

```
import re
def validation(phone):
    answer = re.match(r'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$',phone)
    if(answer is not None):
        return True
    return False
    

phone = input('Enter your phone number (XXX-XXX-XXXX): ')
print(validation(phone))
```

Comment: Well seen, and that's part of the issue, but even with this fix, OP would see None as the answer

Comment: Wow. Looks like I need a lot more work on proofreading. Thank you!

Comment: Or just `return bool(re.match(r'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$',phone))`...